# send a query in neo4j [JAVA]

Tags: java, neo4j

I am new to neo4j and graph database, and I have to send a query to get some values.

I have **food** and **category** nodes, and the relationship type between the two is specified by another node **categorized_as**.

What I need to fetch is the pair of **food_name** and its **category_name**.

Thanks for your help in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[Here's the documentation on how to run cypher queries from java](http://docs.neo4j.org/chunked/stable/tutorials-cypher-java.html).   Adapted for your example, it would look like this:

```
// Create a new graph DB at path DB_PATH
GraphDatabaseService db = new GraphDatabaseFactory().newEmbeddedDatabase( DB_PATH );

// Create a new execution engine for running queries.
ExecutionEngine engine = new ExecutionEngine( db );

ExecutionResult result;

// Queries need to be run inside of transactions...
try ( Transaction ignored = db.beginTx() )
{
    String query = "MATCH (f:food)-[:categorized_as]->(c:category) RETURN f.food_name as foodName, c.category_name as categoryName";

    // Run that query we just defined.
    result = engine.execute(query);

    // Pull out the "foodNames" column from the result indicated by the query.
    Iterator<String> foodNames = result.columnAs( "foodName" );
    // Iterate through foodNames...
}
```

Comment: pro tip here: don't create a fresh `ExecutionEngine` for each query. Instead the executionEngine should be like a singleton, instantiated ones and reused all over the place. The query plan cache is associated to the engine, so recreating it forces the query plan to be calculated over and over again.

Comment: Agreed, but OP seems new and I think hadn't considered basic docs, so I wanted to provide enough scaffold to be useful, rather than just the bit that executes the query.

Comment: Thanks for the quick help. I used the method you mentioned, but I didn't get anything in the Iterator object. The query returned rows in neo4j browser, but the iterator is empty after those steps. Any suggestions?

Comment: Can't tell you what's wrong with the iterator object.  Double check the query and your data.  Most likely the iterator is empty because no results came back from the query.